# Não existe biblioteca chamada math

Tags: python, import

Por que quando importo `sqrt` da livraria `math` ele diz que não existe livraria chamada `math`, mas mesmo assim o código funciona?

Não dá erro funciona de boa, mas fica aquele sublinhado em `math` e `sqrt`. Pra "sanar" enquanto não acho a resposta estou usando `cmath` que seria pra números mais completos correto?

Por que fica sublinhado dizendo que `math` não existe sendo que o código funciona igual?

Comment: Resumindo pra quem tiver o mesmo problema: isso foi um erro específico numa atualização do PyCharm.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Se você usar

```
import math
```

está disponibilizando o módulo `math` para sua aplicação usar. Então precisa chamar a função dentro do módulo, assim:

```
math.sqrt(9)
```

Mas se usar

```
from math import sqrt
```

Está trazendo a função `sqrt` que está em `math` para dentro do escopo do seu código. Então a função está disponível ali mesmo e não precisa, e não pode, chamar pelo módulo original, é como se fosse uma função que você escreveu ali mesmo, assim:

```
sqrt(9)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Import.py).

Só cuidado para não importar desta forma usando o `*` para não poluir o *namespace* com todas funções que você provavelmente não irá usar. Se for importar algumas funções do módulo, prefira a primeira.

Answer (score 1):

Eu descobri ontem mesmo oque aconteceu, eu importo correto e sei que se importo math eu devo usar math.sqrt mas oque aconteceu é que ontem eu tive uma atualização no pycharm que é minha idle e descobri que havia um erro nessa att então oque eu fiz foi instalar uma mais antiga para sanar isso ja reportei aos dev do pycharm, eu descobri pois fui na idle da propria python e nao apareceu tal "erro" obrigado por responder mesmo assim

Answer (score 0):

Siga estes passos, no pycharm:

1) Acesse: File> Settings.

2) No menu lateral clique em: Project: "Nome do projeto" > Project Interpreter.

3) No canto superior direito clique na engrenagem e em seguida em "Add local..."

4) Na janela que irá aparecer marque as opções: "Inherit global site-packages" e "Make available to all projects" e clique em "OK", aguarde o carregamento.

5) Feche o PyCharm e abra novamente e faça o teste!